# Controlling order of execution in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have inherited an angular app and now need to make a change.

As part of this change, some data needs to be set in one controller and then used from another. So I created a service and had one controller write data into it and one controller read data out of it.

```
angular.module('appRoot.controllers')

.controller('pageController', function (myApiService, myService) {
    // load data from API call
    var data = myApiService.getData();

    // Write data into service
    myService.addData(data);
})

.controller('pageSubController', function (myService) {
    // Read data from service
    var data = myService.getData();

    // Do something with data....
})
```

However, when I go to use `data` in `pageSubController` it is always undefined.

How can I make sure that `pageController` executes before `pageSubController`? Or is that even the right question to ask?

**EDIT**

My service code:

```
angular.module('appRoot.factories')

.factory('myService', function () {
    var data = [];

    var addData = function (d) {
        data = d;
    };

    var getData = function () {
        return data;
    };

    return {
        addData: addData,
        getData: getData
    };
})
```

Comment: Can we have a look at `myService` definition? Also your html

Comment: @RahilWazir added. usage of the data is actually in ng-table params

Comment: It would be great if you include your html so we will know how you have used the controllers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your controller to wait untill you get a response from the other controller. You can try using `$broadcast` option in angularjs.

In the pagecontroller, you have to broadcast your message "dataAdded" and in the pagesubcontroller you have to wait for the message using $scope.$on and then process "getData" function.

You can try something like this :

```
angular.module('appRoot.controllers')
.controller('pageController', function (myApiService, myService,$rootScope) {
    // load data from API call
    var data = myApiService.getData();

    // Write data into service
    myService.addData(data);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('dataAdded', data);
})

.controller('pageSubController', function (myService,$rootScope) {
    // Read data from service
    $scope.$on('dataAdded', function(event, data) {
        var data = myService.getData();
    }

    // Do something with data....
})
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a play with this and let you know

Comment: This was just what I needed - a global event which I can hook into. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would change your service to return a promise for the data. When asked, if the data has not been set, just return the promise. Later when the other controller sets the data, resolve the previous promises with the data. I've used this pattern to handle caching API results in a way such that the controllers don't know or care whether I fetched data from the API or just returned cached data. Something similar to this, although you may need to keep an array of pending promises that need to be resolved when the data does actually get set.

```
function MyService($http, $q, $timeout) {
  var factory = {};
  factory.get = function getItem(itemId) {
    if (!itemId) {
      throw new Error('itemId is required for MyService.get');
    }
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (factory.item && factory.item._id === itemId) {
      $timeout(function () {
        deferred.resolve(factory.item);
      }, 0);
    } else {
      $http.get('/api/items/' + itemId).then(function (resp) {
        factory.item = resp.data;
        deferred.resolve(factory.item);
      });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  return factory;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - though I'm not making the api call from the service, just using it to store some data in. Is this not a recommended approach?

Comment: It doesn't seem OP sending any server-side request to retrieve the data. Its just a simple assignment of data to properties.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is your call to `$timeout` redundant? You should be able to just call `deferred.resolve(factory.item)` and return the promise.

Comment: It's pessimistic about [releasing zalgo](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony) by sometimes having same-tick behavior and sometimes having future-tick semantics. This guarantees future-tick semantics 100% of the time.